# Existence and uniqueness of 2nd order linear differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I know that the equation $$\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}+p\left(t\right)\frac{dx}{dt}+q\left(t\right)x=g\left(t\right),$$
has a unique solution on open sets where $p\left(t\right),q\left(t\right)$ and $g\left(t\right)$ are continuous. 
What I was wondering if this fact could be derived from the Picard's Theorem on Uniqueness and Existence of First ODE making the usual substitution $y=x'$ and $y_0=x(t_0)$. If so, why  $p\left(t\right),q\left(t\right)$ do not need to be Lipschitz and only need to be continuous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Picard's theorem for a system $y'(t)=F(t,y)$, $F$ must be continuous in both variables and locally Lipschitz in the $y$ variable. The second order differential equation is equivalent to the system
\begin{align}
x'&=y\\
y'&=-p(t)\,y-q(t)\,x+g(t)
\end{align}
The right hand side is continuous in both variables and Lipschitz in $x,y$.

Comment: So you are positive that the existance and uniqueness of 2nd order linear function can be derived from the Picard's Theorem on Uniqueness and Existence of first order ODE?

Comment: Can you show me why is effectively Lipschitz?

Comment: It is linear in $x$ and $y$.